# Why not all the threads start concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
public class B {
    public static String lock = "a";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread("Thread 1");
        t1.start();

        lock = "b";
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread("Thread 2");
        t2.start();

        lock = "c";
        MyThread t3 = new MyThread("Thread 3");
        t3.start();

        lock = "d";
        MyThread t4 = new MyThread("Thread 4");
        t4.start();
    }

}

class MyThread extends Thread{

    public MyThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (B.lock){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" is going to sleep for 5 seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " done sleeping ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output::

```
Thread 1 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
Thread 2 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
Thread 2 done sleeping 
Thread 1 done sleeping 
Thread 4 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
Thread 4 done sleeping 
Thread 3 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
Thread 3 done sleeping
```

Sorry for the unclear question. But my query here is that as I am changing lock object every time after a thread's start, why not all threads start concurrently and lock different string objects ? I guessed that may be the reason is operating system thread scheduling. But every execution results in starting only 2 threads (1&2) concurrently and remaining 2 threads (3 & 4) awaits for acquiring lock. But why ?

Comment: They don't start concurrently because you're not providing any mechanism for them to start at the same time.

Comment: Side note : Please don't use string literals as *locks*.  If you have this code in multiple classes, your *performance engineer* will have a sev-1 defect named -"The program is too slow".. Next, what is your expected output?.

Comment: Also, the assignment to the `lock` variable after each thread start essentially defeats the `synchronized(B.lock)` construct.  When thread 1 enters the synchronized block, it owns the monitor on the string "a".  However, you then overwrite lock with "b", so when thread 2 enters the synchronized block, it acquires the monitor on "b", and is able to immediately enter the block.  Why are you changing the value of the `lock` variable?

Comment: Also, you aren't guaranteed to have visibility of the updated lock variable in the threads, so you don't really know what you are going to be synchronizing on.

Comment: @schtever I believe what the OP is asking is why do all the threads not start concurrently. If you run this program, you will notice that not all threads start immediately. (On my machine, only two threads can start concurrently at any given time. The other two threads always wait for the first two to complete before they can start)

Comment: @BabuReddyH Good question! How I wish people would read a question properly before commenting or posting answers. Even before the OP edited their question with the additional information, it was pretty clear that the OP wanted to know why the threads don't start concurrently when the locks are changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start all of your threads concurrently, you need to provide some mechanism by which a thread can know that the other threads are ready to execute before it starts working.

Something like a [`java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) will help with this. The basic idea is that the very first thing you do in the thread is to await the `CountDownLatch`; you only count the latch down to zero when all of the threads are created and started.

For example, in your `main` method:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);

MyThread t1 = new MyThread("Thread 1", latch);
t1.start();
//...
MyThread t4 = new MyThread("Thread 4", latch);
t4.start();
```

In your `MyThread`:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    public MyThread(String name, CountDownLatch latch) {
        super(name);
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        latch.countDown();
        latch.await();
        synchronized (B.lock){
          //...
        }
    }
}
```

The threads will now all attempt to enter the `synchronized` block at the same time. Clearly, only one of them will execute that block at any one time, however.

Comment: If OP asks to not noly start, but also run all threads concurrently, I would recommend to add one more attribute to `MyThread`, acting as a lock within the `synchronized`-block.

Comment: He could simply synchronize on `latch`, no? And I can't see him ask anything, other than in the title.

Comment: @AndyTurner I believe what the OP is asking is why do all the threads not start concurrently. If you run this program, you will notice that not all threads start immediately. (On my machine, only two threads can start concurrently at any given time. The other two threads always wait for the first two to complete before they can start)

Comment: @CKing OK, so you could initialize the latch with 4, and decrement in `MyThread.run`.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's not the point of the question. The OP wants to know *why* does his code behave this way and not how to fix it.

Comment: @CKing please see the first paragraph of my answer: that explains exactly why they don't start at the same time. Call me naive, but I thought he might want to know how to fix it too.

Comment: @AndyTurner The latch in this code has the semantics of controlling the start of the treads. The `synchronized`-block guards some statements to be executed in parallel (independelty from the latch, maybe some calculation beforehand must be finished before this block is executed). With your argumentation, OP would not need to use the `synchronized` block.

Comment: @AndyTurner You don't answer the question. Why does the code presented in the question work this way? Even before the OP edited the question, it was pretty clear that the threads were not starting concurrently even when the lock was changed. That's the question to be answered.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, I understood what I need to do to execute all threads concurrently for sure. But Why  can't I execute them concurrently in above code.

Comment: @CKing please provide your own answer rather than just picking holes in mine.

Comment: @AndyTurner I am sorry if it looked like I was picking on you. That was not my intention. When you post an answer that does not answer the question, other users might know of it and might just walk away from the question rather than giving it a second look.

Comment: I don't think you are picking on me (look for what I mean by "picking holes" on a search engine of your choice), I just think that you consider that you have a better understanding of the question. Please, give your answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't have the answer. That does not mean I can't point out that your answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is inspired by [Andy Turner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502954/why-not-all-the-threads-start-concurrently/31503476#comment50969025_31502954).

On the matter of **why** the program behaves as it does: `B.lock` is not the value you think it is. I modified your source code slightly.

```
public class B {
    public static String lock = "a";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        lock = "a";

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread("Thread 1");
        t1.start();
        lock = "b";

        MyThread t2 = new MyThread("Thread 2");
        t2.start();
        lock = "c";

        MyThread t3 = new MyThread("Thread 3");
        t3.start();
        lock = "d";

        MyThread t4 = new MyThread("Thread 4");
        t4.start();
        // lock = "e";
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    public MyThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String s = B.lock;
        synchronized (s) {
            System.out.println(  Thread.currentThread()
                                       .getName()
                               + " is going to sleep for 5 seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(  Thread.currentThread().getName()
                               + " done sleeping ");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + s);
    }
}
```

Please understand that, from here on out, I can only explain the behaviour of my machine since the behaviour is highly dependent on the host system you run it on. The solution I provide, however, should be independent from the host system.

If I execute this code, I get some output like this:

> Thread 2 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
>
> Thread 3 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
>
> Thread 1 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
>
> Thread 1 done sleeping
>
> Thread 1: b
>
> Thread 3 done sleeping
>
> Thread 2 done sleeping
>
> Thread 2: c
>
> Thread 3: d
>
> Thread 4 is going to sleep for 5 seconds
>
> Thread 4 done sleeping
>
> Thread 4: d

So as you see, the start of the threads is slighly delayed. By this time, the `main` method has already changed the `lock` field. Therefore the last thread starts late.

If I un-comment the final line, the program ran as expected (but this is by no means guaranteed).

To fix this problem, I added an `Object lock` to `MyThread` and set it via constructor.

```
public class B {
    public static String lock = "a";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        lock = "a";

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread("Thread 1", lock);
        t1.start();
        lock = "b";

        MyThread t2 = new MyThread("Thread 2", lock);
        t2.start();
        lock = "c";

        MyThread t3 = new MyThread("Thread 3", lock);
        t3.start();
        lock = "d";

        MyThread t4 = new MyThread("Thread 4", lock);
        t4.start();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    Object lock;
    
    public MyThread(String name, Object lock) {
        super(name);
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println(  Thread.currentThread()
                                       .getName()
                               + " is going to sleep for 5 seconds");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(  Thread.currentThread().getName()
                               + " done sleeping ");
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + lock);
    }
}
```

This way, you decouple the acquiring of the `lock` from the actual setting of it and you have full control on which `lock` object is used in which `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

One educational hint would be to try to print the actual `B.lock` in your thread together with your message:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String currLock = B.lock;
    synchronized (currLock){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" is going to sleep for 5 seconds locking " + currLock);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " done sleeping ");
    }
}
```

It may differ between systems, but I'm getting this output:

```
Thread 1 is going to sleep for 5 seconds locking c
Thread 3 is going to sleep for 5 seconds locking d
Thread 1 done sleeping 
Thread 3 done sleeping 
Thread 2 is going to sleep for 5 seconds locking c
Thread 4 is going to sleep for 5 seconds locking d
Thread 4 done sleeping 
Thread 2 done sleeping
```

(Well, sometimes I get a bit different output, but let's look at what we got here).

By the time thread 1 got to lock the lock, it has already changed values two times. So it's locking on `"c"`. Thread 2, it appears, also was unfortunate enough to get `"c"`, and since that's already locked, it's waiting and not printing.

By the time thread 3 gets to run, the value has already changed to `"d"` and that's what it's locking. Thread 4 also got that lock, so it is also delayed.

So some of the delay may be due to the operating system that can't truly run threads together. But some of it is due to the simple fact that `start()` is not guaranteed to start the `run` method before the next step in `main` is taken. By the time control is transferred to `run()`, the `lock` may have changed values twice. And operations could have been reordered.

`Thread.start()` really doesn't say that the thread will start immediately - it needs to be scheduled, and a frame needs to be prepared for the `run` method, and by that time, things in the other thread may be happening - like strings being assigned, other threads created, etc.

You're almost guaranteed that thread 1 won't be locking on `"a"`, and therefore there is going to be some contest over the lock.

Comment: Note that I tried the same test but in my case, all the threads locked on "d" and yet did not start concurrently. That's why I did not post this explanation as an answer. All threads lock on "d" and yet only two of them can ever run concurrently? One thing is for certain, this program allows two threads to run concurrently on most machines. Why so when the lock is on the same value "d" is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @CKing, how could they start concurrently (as in, print the first message) if they are locking on the same lock, and printing after they got the lock? Note that if you added another `println()` before the lock, you have been synchronizing the threads on `System.out`.

Comment: @CKing did you store `B.lock` in a local variable before entering the `synchronized` block?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The only change I made to the OP's code was that I added a `System.out.println` after the `sycnrhonized(B.lock)` statement. That is, `synchronized (B.lock){
         System.out.println("locked on "+B.lock);`. The surprising part is that it always prints *locked on d* and yet only two threads can run concurrently and this is the only consistent behavior.

Comment: @Turing85 Nope. Just added a `System.out` statement as mentioned in the previous comment above ^^

Comment: @CKing First, you realize that there is a gap between synchronizing on `B.lock` and printing `B.lock`, and during this gap its value can change. That's why I used a local variable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Makes sense. Let me understand your answer with this new (should have been obvious) realization.

Comment: @CKing furthermore, I added a `System.out.println(B.lock)` **before** the `synchronized`-block. This changed the execution behaviour for me drastically (all threads synchronized on `"d"`). Therefore, I took the approach shown in my answer.

Comment: @Turing85 Makes sense. Learnt something new.